# Why does my countlines function always return 0?

Tags: c++

So I am making a program for a simple calendar app which reads in inputs from a file input.csv (its a text file with two columns which are seperated using commas and new lines for each command).

The first thing i want to do is count the number of lines from the input file, which is passed as the third argument in the command line, so I can make an array to hold each line separately but the function countLines always returns 0!

Project code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;


//Prototypes
int countLines (ifstream& countfiles);


int countLines(ifstream& countfile)
//counts number of lines in file passed to function
{
   string line;
   int numberOfLines;

   numberOfLines = 0;

   //reads through each line until end of file
   while(getline(countfile, line))
   {
       numberOfLines++;
   }

   return numberOfLines;
}


int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{

    if(argc != 3) cout << "Usage: calendar.out datafile inputfile";

    //Create input streams to both files
    ifstream apptsfp;
    ifstream inputfp;

    //Open streams to both files
    apptsfp.open(argv[2]);
    inputfp.open(argv[3]);

        int numberOfInputs=0;

    numberOfInputs = countLines(inputfp)-1;

        cout << "number of input commands: " << numberOfInputs << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: At what point do you validate the file opened successfully?

Comment: Sorry! I mistyped the title, i changed it now. It always returns 0 no matter how many lines the input file is.

Comment: Debug it and see that the `getline` even works for you. it may fail if the file wasn't opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access `argv[3]` which is null. Try this :-

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{

    if(argc != 3)
        cout << "Usage: calendar.out datafile inputfile";

    //Create input streams to both files
    ifstream apptsfp;
    ifstream inputfp;

    //Open streams to both files
    apptsfp.open(argv[1]);
    inputfp.open(argv[2]);

    int numberOfInputs=0;

    numberOfInputs = countLines(inputfp)-1;

    cout << "number of input commands: " << numberOfInputs << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Almost certainly because you are failing to open your input file.

```
inputfp.open(argv[3]);
if (!inputfp.is_open())
{
    cerr << "failed to open input file " << argv[3] << '\n';
    return 1;
}
```

Files can fail to open for all sorts of reasons, you should always check for this.

BTW don't use an array to hold the input lines, use `std::vector<std::string>`. Then you can use `push_back` to add the lines to the vector. This will be easier *and* more efficient because you won't have to read the file twice. What more could you ask for!

```
std::vector<std::string> lines;
std::string line;
while (getline(inputfp, line))
    lines.push_back(line);
```

Comment: i will have to look into that fucntion as i am not sure how it works, but thanks for the advice, that showed that i wasnt actually opening the file!

Comment: you mean vector and push_back? A vector is a like an array but it grows dynamically, push_back adds an item to the end of the vector for instance.

Comment: oh wow, i am fairly new to C++ so i have never seen the vector object. This is super neat, can you access its entries like an array?

Comment: yes, `lines[i]` works just like an array, `lines.size()` will tell you how big the vector is.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you only want *two* arguments, not three as you say in the question (the "first" argument is the program name). This means that the input file is in `argc[2]` instead, and `argv[3]` is a `NULL` pointer.

This means that your `open` call will fail, but you do not check for that.

Answer (score 2):

Your access to `argv[3]` is incorrect. The second file name (third arg, including the program name in `arg[0]`) is in slot 2 (the array is zero-based).

Try:

> ```
> apptsfp.open(argv[1]);
> inputfp.open(argv[2])
> ```